# Python - Finding total number of pages of a REST API

Tags: python, rest, pagination, python-requests

I am trying to loop through a REST API and fetch the complete data set.

```
url = f'https://apiurl.com/api/1.1/json/tickets?page=1'
auth = (f'{api_key}', f'{auth_code}')
res = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
data = json.loads(res.content)
```

The above returns data for `page 1` and I am able to do it for all other pages, page by page by specifying the page number in the URL. I am not sure how do I find the total pages such that I can perform a for loop that does it for all pages in the API feed.

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the total number of pages?

Comment: if you cannot determine the amount of pages beforehand, you can always try a while loop to increment the page number in the url until a failed response is returned

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the number of pages using the below code:

```
res = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
data=res.json()

while 'next' in res.links.keys():
    res = requests.get(res.links['next']['url'])
    data.extend(res.json())


page_count = repos['page_info']['page_count'] <<-- This returns the max page count
```